Story about a LLM-ish machine trained on Nebula winners, and published under girlfriend's name
While talking about Asimov's "The Monkey's Finger", a friend mentioned a story they can't find about other such writing machines:

Story produced was called "Forever Plus"
Machine was trained on Nebula Award winners, "the actual story had to be mid-80s because Claw of the Conciliator was specifically mentioned amongst the Nebula winners"
"the user was so well known in the SF community as a total hack that he got it published under his girlfriend's name"
"this is literally a retrospective, like the narrator is listening to the news reports on the ongoing lawsuits and debate in the publishing industry and reflecting on what's been going on"

And Googling for "Forever Plus" and "Claw of the Conciliator" couldn't get anything.

"The Great Nebula Sweep", a short story in the form of a book review, by Paul Di Filippo; first published in the 1991 anthology Nebula Awards 25 (Michael Bishop, ed.); reprinted in the 2006 Di Filippo collection Plumage from Pegasus which can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive.
Plot summary from the NESFA Recursive Science Fiction site:

Harley Prout is an unsuccessful SF writer. He develops and programs a neural network, using the Nebula Award winners as input, to generate a story "Forever Plus!"  Since his name is so well-known to editors, he submits it under the name of his new girl friend Amber Max. The short story version is published in the January 1992 issue of Omni; the novelet comes out from Axolotl Press in March; the novella version is published as a Tor double in May; finally it is expanded to a 500,000 word novel, published by Bantam/Foundation in August. The next year it wins the Nebula in all four categories. In addition, Lucasfilms brings out the movie in time to receive the re-established Dramatic Production Nebula. Prout, angered at the attention Max is getting, tells all.

The exact title Claw of the Conciliator is not in the story, but something close:

All the story lacked was a title. Harley ran a simple subroutine that permuted all previous Nebula titles, and passed the choices on to the judgment of the network.
DOORS OF REPENTENCE, BLIND CONCILIATOR, ENEMY CLAW, SLOW PASSENGERS, A LETTER FROM THE KING OF SAND, DANCING CHICKENS AND UGLY DEERS, GOD SONG, BORN WITH THE SHADOWS, THE QUICKENING FLUTE, CATCH THAT HANGMAN, CHILDMANCER, MOTHER TO DRAGONS, THE FOUNTAINS OF SALIVA, DREAM OF THE LEFT-HANDED SNAKE, HARD BLOOD, THE VISION SOLUTION, THE PLANNERS OF TIME, THE GIRL WHO FELL INTO THE UNICORN TAPESTRY, A HELIX OF MIST, A DOG’S OPINION, PRESS LOVE OR DEATH, REVOLUTION MAN, ENDER IS FIVE, A TIME OF WORLDS, RINGWAY ... All these and more met the thumbs-down from the network. Then came the winner: FOREVER PLUS!

How to find stories like this. I followed a less efficient route, but this question could have been answered in seconds by Googling <site:https://data.nesfa.org/Recursion "forever plus">. The New England Science Fiction Association's Recursive Science Fiction database contains many such "science fiction stories about science fiction."

Seems to be it! No reason not to Checkmark!

"The fountains of saliva" , sounds like a winner.

@user108131 All the fake story titles are wonderful ad hilarious. If you've read a lot of science fiction, you will know their origin. "Dream of the Left-handed Snake" is a take-off from Vonda McIntyre, for instance. "The Fountains of Saliva" is unmistakably Arthur C. Clarke. And so on. Fun stuff.

To expand on that, "Dream of the Left-handed Snake" is taken from both Vonda McIntyre and Ursula K.LeGuin and I suspect that many (or maybe all) of the other titles are similar mashups. I can't identify them all offhand. Doing so might be a good question on Puzzling.

@Wastrel Clarke + Aldiss "The Saliva Tree"
